# ¿Por qué no se cumple la condición con el while hasta que se introduzca lo incorrecto y el alert dentro del ciclo no aparece?

Tags: javascript, bucles, while

Lo que se quiere hacer es que mientras el usuario ingrese un numero menor o igual a 10 el sistema siga preguntando hasta que no se cumpla esta condición. No sé si es que se eligió el ciclo/bucle incorrecto o si se puede hacer con el while

```
let ingresarNumero = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar un número"));
//Se repite el ciclo hasta que el usuario ingresa algún número menor o igual a 10
while(ingresarNumero >= "10" ){
    alert("Usted ingresó el número"+ ingresarNumero + "" + "... debe ingresar un número mayor");
    //Se vuelve a solicitar un dato. En la próxima iteración se evalúa si la condición se cumple o no.
    let ingresarNumero = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar otro número"));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dos cosas:

1. No se realizará la comparación con un string.
2. ingresarNumero ya está declarado.

Teniendo esto en cuenta si haces:

```js
let ingresarNumero = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar un número"));
//LO COMPARO CON VALOR NUMÉRICO
while(ingresarNumero <= 10 ){
    alert("Usted ingresó el número"+ ingresarNumero + "" + "... debe ingresar un número mayor");
    //QUITO EL LET PORQUE YA ESTÁ DECLARADO FUERA
    ingresarNumero = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar otro número"));
}
```

Funciona correctamente.

Comment: El signo debe ser menor igual, según el planteamiento del op, solo eso y listo